# How do I create a select on a frontend template from custom member data?

Tags: members, forms, solspace-user

So, in a member profile, I have created a custom field for company_state as a select and its populated with the US States. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to render out a select with those options for selection in a frontend form (I am using Solspace User's user:edit if it matters.)

Anybody know how to do this? Would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
{exp:user:edit}  
     <select name="company_state">
            {select_company_state}
                <option value="{value}" {selected}>{value}</option>
            {/select_company_state}
      </select>
     <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
{/exp:user:edit}
```

> This variable pair is a flexible method for creating pull-down menus,
>   radio button arrays, etc. In the variable pair, you precede the
>   short_name of the member field with select_. Providing your member
>   field is a Select field with multiple values, it will automatically
>   generate those values for you. Within this variable pair, the
>   following variables become available:
>
> **value** - the values stored as options for the member field.
>       **selected** - parses to selected="selected" if the option is the current value for the users' profile.
>       **option_index** - behaves like a count variable and displays the display order of each value.

**http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/#select_custom_member_field**